# passing an html parameter to my view then using it in my object.get()

Tags: django-views

I have two parameters I wish to use to get a single row from my database and use that in my template.

my url looks like:

`enter code here`

{{ divisions }}

my view looks like this but doesn't work:

```
class detailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = divisiondisplay
    template_name = 'wondjinainfo/detail.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
        divisiondisplay.objects.get(divisioncode = divisioncode,freetradezone = freetradezone)
```

and my model looks like:

```
class divisiondisplay(models.Model):
    freetradezone = models.ForeignKey(ftz, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    divisioncode =  models.IntegerField()
    bodytext = models.TextField()
    imagename = models.CharField(max_length = 25)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.bodytext
```

how can I use those two parameters to select my row

I tried this change:

```
divisiondisplay.objects.get(divisioncode = self.kwargs['divisioncode'],freetradezone = self.kwargs['freetradezone'])
```

it got me new error of: Generic detail view detailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug.

Answer (score 0):

because my model needed to be searched by fields other than the keys. the detail generic view was the wrong solution.  I defined my own view and used it:
def divisiondisplay_detail_view(request,freetradezone, divisioncode):
    try:
        sometext = divisiondisplay.objects.get(divisioncode = divisioncode, freetradezone = freetradezone)
    except divisiondisplay.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404('Book does not exist')

```
# from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
# book = get_object_or_404(Book, pk=primary_key)

return render(request, 'wondjinainfo/detail.html', context={'sometext': sometext})
```